# Createjs DOMElement with css filter (-webkit-filter) in Chrome

Tags: javascript, filter, easeljs, createjs

I try to combine canvas and DOMElement (with SVG background for scalable buttons) but if the DOMElement has a class with filter and -webkit-filter (drop-shadow), then these element appear behind any drawed Shape. (in Firefox the z-order is perfect.)
You can see here:

[image]

The upper one is from Chrome, the icon is behind the semi-transparent panel.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: If I set the position into the window's upper half then after (in 10-30 ms) at the bottom, the DOMElement appears. Strange, after every resize event need to be done this.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a browser bug to me.